# Why can't I use all my 8 GB RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory

Windows 7 can only use 7.87 GB of my 8 GB RAM. Why is this? I am using a dedicated graphics card, so I ruled out the use of shared memory with my built-in graphics.

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/81094/4-00gb-3-25gb-usable-in-windows-7-x64?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the integrated GPU of your CPU is still enabled. So go to the BIOS/UEFI and disable it if you only want to use the dedicated one.

Comment: Yep, 128MB missing, a typical integrated GPU memory size.

Comment: It can be the integrated GPU, but also memory mapped buffers of other expansion cards. (Audio cards, ethernet, SAS, or SCSI controllers often need some buffer space too but that amount is so small (couple of Megabytes usually) it disappears in the round-off error when you convert to Gigabytes.)

Comment: In my bios, I have 2 options: as seen here https://scontent-b-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/v/1238344_583905168311391_303353287_n.jpg?oh=2dd36c7e2c3aaff25a935f8e1b822be1&oe=524A5F98 ...What is the difference between the 2 and both options still do not let me get the full 8 gb

Comment: this is strange the description of the second entry shows that it should disable the integrated GPU if an PCIe card is installed. Try a BIOS/UEFI update, maybe a newer version fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok, so what is the point of auto? What is the point of it if it uses my discrete but leaves the integrated on?

Comment: Ive tried every setting in bios and updated to the newest, it is still not working. Could it be some other card? I have a wifi card and a pci express card (nvidia). Could it be something like the agp aperture (even though i don't have agp)

Comment: Read this, try the device manager way he uses to find which device causes the gap: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Microsoft Website: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610

Quoted:

> The amount of usable memory in the examples are not exact amounts. Usable memory is a calculated amount of the total physical memory minus "hardware reserved" memory.

They have more information there as what may caused it, and what to try to test the RAM.