# Windows 7 x64 3.2Gb RAM usable instead of 4Gb installed

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have two questions that bothers me, and for which I couldn't find an adequate answers here.

This is my laptop's configuration: HP Probook 455 G1 (Windows 7 Ultimate x64)

- AMD A8-4500M - 1.96Ghz
- 4096Mb RAM
- Chipset AMD A70M Fusion
- Chiptype    (dxdiag) AMD Radeon HD 7640G...
- Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 8750 2Gb

First, I have a memory problem. In myComputer it displays that only 3.2Gb out of 4Gb is in use. I tried suggestions to change the BIOS but couldn't find where? And in msconfig the maximum memory isn't checked.

Second, because I have 4Gb RAM, and I expect nice performance. Should I buy another RAM module, also 4Gb, so I would have 8Gb in total. When I do that, would it be better for playing games (B4, MW, FC3, etc) and what amount of memory should be usable then? 6.4 or...?

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

What to do? Should I change anything now, or leave the 3.2GB? If yes, where and how...
Should I upgrade RAM?

Comment: How it is indicates I'm not using 64bit OS. I have installed W7 Ultimate x64. And in screenshot you can see that it says 64-bit Operating System. I am obviously missing something, can you guide me where I am wrong and how to set it right. So I shouldn't buy more memory, it won't have effect?

Comment: No: more memory won't help with BF4 performance...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/35731/how-to-enable-4gb-in-my-windows-7-64-bit, http://superuser.com/questions/81094/4-00gb-3-25gb-usable-in-windows-7-x64?rq=1

Comment: very simply, for better performance in games, you want a dedicated graphics card. 8GB will not help that  much because the games simply don't use it: many of them stream data and.or precache in dedicated VRAM on the GPU add-in card.

Answer (score 2):

your graphics cards are using some of the memory, the on die 7640G uses atleast ~512MB

Comment: So if I upgrade it on 8Gb, it will have something like 7.5 Gb. I am afraid it will stuck on 3.2 and I waste my money

Comment: @user3244442 If you're afraid to try anything, why are you here? :)  Take it to a computer store and get them to try it, if it works, buy the RAM from them and you're done.

Comment: That's the procedure that I would follow :) This laptop is weak, but I will try to use the maximum of it

Comment: it isnt that weak, it has a quad core, and real graphics, meybe reinstall windows, update drivers, upgrade to a SSD (omfg, this is the best path) or more ram (i think a ssd will be a better us of money)