# 14gb ram installed, only 6gb detected

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance

I've checked each stick individually in the computer, by itself, to verify that the RAM was all in working condition.  I have 2 sticks of 4gb RAM and 2 sticks of 3gb RAM.  I'm not sure which are being detected and which aren't.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

system specs (AS SHOWN)

Windows Edition: Windows 7 Home Premium
processor: AMD Athlon II X4 620 Processor 2.60GHz
Installed Memory (RAM): 6.00GB (3.25GB usable)
System Type: 32-bit Operating System

Everything I've seen related to the subject is in regards to the amount of usable RAM being less than the amount installed. This is not my main issue, I have 14GB of RAM (2 sticks 2X2G DDR3, 2 sticks 3x1G DDR3), and only 6GB is shown as installed, with only 3.25GB of that usable.

Comment: There no such thing as 3GB RAM sticks and the number and capacity of the RAM sticks change through-out your question; So your question really makes no sense.  Can you please double check your actual RAM stick capacities and amounts and update your question?

Comment: @Joseph - 2GB + 2GB + 1GB + 1GB + 1GB isn't 16GB. Besides your running a 32-bit operating system there is NO WAY for a 32-bit operating system to use 16GB. Your hard limit on Home Premium is 16GB by the way. [Memory Limits Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)

Comment: You also have an odd number of modules (7) instead of (8) which is more then the AM3 socket even supported.  The only way you would have 8 memory modules is if you had a dual-socket motherboard.  Update your question with percise specifcations and fix the numerous errors in your question....

Comment: There is such a thing as x86 machines which can address more than the 3 Gb limit, but it requires a PAE kernel (something that, to my knowledge, Windows does not have).

Answer (score 6):

You're using a 32-bit operating system. 32-bit Windows cannot assign enough memory addresses to account for all 14 gigabytes.

You'd have to be using 64-bit Windows in order to use that much memory.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer his question. He didn't ask why only 3.25GB was usable but why only 6GB was detected.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that could be any number of things, I suppose... maybe his motherboard has some sort of limit to it. 

That being said, it won't matter as long as he's on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: I have an ATI Radeon HD 4800 series. Would the upgrade to 64-bit solve my problem?

Comment: That's [not quite true](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/license/memory.htm). Also, installing a 64-bit Windows version [doesn't always help](http://superuser.com/questions/81094/).

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you need a 64-bit operating system to use more than 3GB. This is known as the [3 Gigabit Barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier),

> "the 3 GB barrier[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier) is a limitation of some 32-bit operating systems running on x86 microprocessors. It prevents the operating systems from using more than about 3 GB (3 × 1024<sup>3</sup> bytes) of main memory (RAM). The exact barrier varies by motherboard and I/O device configuration"

A 64-bit version of Home Premium can be found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-home-premium-64bit-iso-download/709dcc12-d120-435d-91cd-52e1dd0f4c24).

Comment: I've only ever installed a OS from a cd, being an iso file, will I need to burn this to a cd, or can it be installed in another way?

Comment: @Joseph You may burn it to a cd using software such as [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) or you could mount it to a bootable flash drive with [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).   The flash drive will behave just like your Windows 7 installation cd at your computer's boot

Comment: Ok, would I be able to download that to a bit torrent application like Vuze and burn the cd directly from that program? and one last question, is Microsoft gonna sue me? lol

Comment: I'm unaware of any legal torrents, I'd use something like [downthemall!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) or [Free Download Manager](http://alternativeto.net/software/free-download-manager/) if you have an unstable internet connection. As for lawsuits, the download contains only the iso. No cracks or keygens are provided within the iso. As long as you have a legitimate key for Home Premium, I think you should be fine.

Comment: The linked article also reads: "It is a common misconception that 32-bit processors and operating systems are limited to 4 GB [of RAM]." 32-bit operating systems can use [more than 3 GB](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/license/memory.htm).

Comment: @Joseph No need to use torrents. You can [get the official ISO image legally](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/).

Comment: @and31415 Good find. I was unaware Windows x32 could exceed even 3GB. PAE is an interesting idea! I found further details at [Microsoft's Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366796%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

You can only use 4 GB at a time as you have installed a 32-bit operating system, to use all of those memory, you need to upgrade to an 64-bit OS. Your processor supports 64-bit and every of windows 7 purchases have both 32 and 64 bit OS bundled in them

Your question is confusing. Please edit it.